# What does a high branch efficiency and low control flow efficiency indicate?

Tags: cuda

I used Parallel Nsight 2.2 to profile my code written in CUDA 4.2. The result is: **branch efficiency=0.9**, while **control flow execution efficiency=0.26**.

From the user guide,

```
Branch Efficiency=({Branches} - {Diverged Branches}) / {Branches}
Control Flow Efficiency={Thread Instructions Executed} / {Instructions Executed} / {Warps Size}
```

I'm confused: isn't a higher branch efficiency implying that there are more active threads executing the same instruction within a warp and hence a higher control flow efficiency? and what does a high branch efficiency and low control flow efficiency indicate? Thanks a lot for any comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Branch Efficiency** is a measure of how many branches diverged. 100% means no branches diverged. When a branch diverges the warp thread active mask is reduce to be less than 32 so the execution is not as efficient. In addition the branch may have to be executed multiple times based upon the number of ways the branch diverged.

**Thread Instructions Executed** counts predicated off threads. The compiler can use predicate flags to avoid control flow divergence. It is possible to see 100% for this counter for code that has small conditional blocks of executed code.

**Control Flow Efficiency** is a measure of how many threads in a warp were active for each instruction. Unless you launch a non-multiple of 32 threads this will be 32 threads or 100%. This number will be less than 100% if the code diverges.

**Example 1** : You launch 32 threads per block and have no divergent branches.

Branch Efficiency = 100%
Control Flow Efficiency = 100%

**Example 2** : You launch 1 thread per block and have no divergent branches.

Branch Efficiency = 100%
Control Flow Efficiency = 3% (1/32)

**Example 3** : You launch 32 threads per block and diverge on the first instruction by 2 ways (even threads go one direction, odd threads go another) and execute the diverge block until exit. Assume this is the only branch.

Branch Efficiency = 0% (may be higher on some devices as exits are counted as branches)
Control Flow Efficiency = 50% (only executing 16 threads/warp most of the time)

Comment: thanks for the good examples. Very helpful! I use 1 million threads in total and the dim of each block is 512, so the non-multiple-of-32-threads-per-block problem seems to be trivial (only occurs to the last block). May I instead attribute my problem to "Although the diverged branches only occupy a small portion of all branching conditions, only a few threads take them and it is these branches that take a long time to run"?

Comment: A .9 branch efficieny is evidence that you few divergent branches. A .26 control flow efficiency is evidence that a few of the divergent branches execute a lot of instructions. The duration of the instructions is not part of the calculation. The calculation only takes into account the number of instructions executed. If you do not know where this is occurring I would recommend you use the CUDA debugger and step the code. The CUDA Info Window Warps view will show you the thread active mask. The upcoming version of Nsight CUDA Profiler will show this information per source line or instruction.